# Does killing wards increase my CS?

Tags: league-of-legends

Warding is a key factor in LoL. Killing wards is also important. But does killing/destroying a ward increase your CS?

Comment: If I'm remembering right, wards, traps, and pets all count toward CS. I'm not sure though, so I'm not putting it as an answer yet.

Comment: yes,i would know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Wards will count towards your CS score.

Things that count are:

- Champion Pets (Tibbers, Heimer turrets,Teemo Shrooms, Yorick ghouls etc.)
- Jungle monsters
- Minions killed by an ally with relic shileld (or any higher form)
- Wards (Pinks and trinkets included)

Comment: Wow, that's pretty interesting. It makes sense now that I think about it--seems to be pretty much anything that gives you gold.